# Bash script help, include sub-directories for processing files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am definitely new to scripting.  I have a script that processes some files and I can't figure out how to run this against all files in a directory that has many sub-directories and thousands of files.  Basically I want to take this script and run it against a directory titled 2011 and have it process every file in every sub-folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=./userfiles/*
for f in $FILES
do
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "Processing File $f ...."
    echo ""
    echo ""
    make FILE_TYPE=user CSS_PATH=./log.css SCRIPT_PATH=./toggle.js SAXON_JAR=/opt/saxon/saxon9he.jar $f.html
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "File $f.html Generated"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The following script will recurse into every directory under `./userfiles` and work on all files there, even ones with spaces in their names (or other nefarious characters).

Also, the way you have the script written, *make* will be passed as its last argument the filename as it appears on your disk appended with `.html`.  For example, the file `./userfiles/subdir/foobar.txt` will be passed to *make* as `./userfiles/subdir/foobar.txt.html`.  If this is not what you want, then adjust `${file}.html` accordingly.

Additionally, if you want `find` to *only* work on files ending in, for example, `.html`, then you can append the option `-name "*.html"` to the `find` command anywhere after the pathname.

```
#!/bin/bash

topLevelDir="./userfiles"

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    echo 
    echo 
    echo "Processing File $file ...."
    echo 
    echo 
    make FILE_TYPE=user CSS_PATH=./log.css SCRIPT_PATH=./toggle.js SAXON_JAR=/opt/saxon/saxon9he.jar "${file}".html
    echo  
    echo  
    echo "File $file.html Generated"
done < <(find "$topLevelDir" -type f -print0)
```

Comment: With all that protection on the `read` command, I'm pretty sure the `find` needs a `print0` at the end. You can do `-d ''`, by the way.

Comment: @Dennis heh crap. Thanks for pointing out that oversight. Wasn't aware that `-d ''` was equivalent, but I think I like the more explicit one a tad bit better.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this is helpful.  What I am trying to do is get the script to run on a directory titled 2011, and then have it run on every sub-directory below that and every file.

Comment: Hi, I tried, the script above but i get an error which I pasted below.  I copied the entire "2011" directory I mentioned into a folder titled "userfiles" and then ran the script from the folder where I have the "makefile" and other components I need to have in there for the script I pasted initially to run.

Comment: @user are you *sure* you copied it correctly? it looks like you have `le IFS= ...` instead of `while IFS= ...`

Comment: Hi, I will try again. Thanks!  I also tried to delete line 1 from the script I posted and then put this on line 2, but it seems to get stuck looping over & over in "some" folders, but it doesn't go through all the folders..

Comment: Hi, I tried it again, here is what I have and now I am getting a different error.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

while IFS=read -r -d $'\0' file; do'
    echo
    echo
    echo "Processing File $file ...."
    echo
    echo
    make FILE_TYPE=user CSS_PATH=./log.css SCRIPT_PATH=./toggle.js SAXON_JAR=/opt/saxon/saxon9he.jar ${file}.html
    echo
    echo
    echo "File $file.html Generated"
done < <(find ./userfiles -type f -print0)

Comment: +1. The expansion of `${file}` on the make command line is not quoted and probably should be. The directory `./userfiles` probably ought to be a parameter passed in to the script (this may also help the with the user's invocation issues).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `find` command to get the list of all file and directories

Comment: I know how to use Find, but I am not sure how to use find and then have it run against all files it finds?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your script does, but in order to run it for every file in a tree starting at the current folder you can use:

```
find . -exec yourscript.sh {} \;
```

Comment: But if I run this, then how do I deal with the Files= parameter which specifies a specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

Since your script already understands one level of file expansion, perhaps running it on every directory containing a `./userfiles` directory would be fast and simple...

```
$ find . -type d -a -name userfiles -a -exec sh /whatever/myscript {}/.. \;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. The script takes a text file and converts it to a .html file.  The problem I have is that I have a top level folder titled 2011 and under that folder I have a folder for each month of the year, and in each months folder there is a folder for each day of the month.  I want to take the script and run it against the "year" folder and have it parse through every folder and convert every file it finds to the .html format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does what you ask, you pass it a folder see the call at the bottom func_process_folder_set "/folder".

```
    # --- -------------------------------- --- #
    # FUNC:  Process a folder of files
    # --- -------------------------------- --- #
    func_process_folder_set(){

        FOLDER="${1}"

        while read -rd $'\0' file; do

            fileext=${file##*.}  # -- get the .ext of file
            case ${fileext,,}    # -- make ext lowercase for checking in case statement
            echo "FILE: $file"   # -- print the file  (always use " " to handle file spaces)

        done < <(find  ${FOLDER} -type f -maxdepth 20 -name '*.*' -print0)

    }

    # -- call the function above with this:
    func_process_folder_set "/some/folder"
```